# can't find the method I added to the external javascript library

Tags: javascript, prototype, jspdf, prototype-chain

I'm a new for Javascript.
I wanted to add a method to the external library named jsPDF.
so I tried to add a function named 'addHangle' to jsPDF.prototype
But the object of jsPDF didn't find my method.

I've tried debugging and I found out jsPDF.prototype is pointer for Object.prototype

Why does it happend? I thought doc.construct is pointer for jsPDF and doc.__proto__ is pointer for jsPDF.prototype

Is there anyone know the reason? please tell me.
my code is below.

```
jsPDF.prototype.addHangle = function(x, y, text) { 
  // some logic for supporting Korean
};

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.addHangle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because jsPDF constructor returns API object.
Following example might help you to understand why `doc`'s prototype is not a `jsPDF`

```
var P = function() {
    var API = {};

    // This is constructor of P
    function P() {
      // Do something...
      API.a = function(val){return val};
      return API;
    }

    return P;
};

var p = new P();
var result = p instanceof P; // false
```

You can see what really happens when `new jsPDF()` called at [jsPDF GitHub](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js)

If you want to insert your own method, you have to make it as jsPDF plugin.
You can refer other plugins of jsPDF at https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/plugins

Answer (score -1):

hi follow the link https://github.com/happymishra/JavaScriptTutorials/blob/master/Part2/Prototypes.md

you will get idea of prototypes